# What is the value of $142,857 \times 7^2$?

Tags: arithmetic

> What is the value of $142,857 \times 7^2$?

Obviously you could solve this with a calculator and be done. But is there a more clever way to calculate this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do you recognize that $1/7=0.\overline{142857}?$  If so, you will recognize that $142,857 \cdot 7 = 999,999,$ so $142,857 \cdot 7^2=(1,000,000-1)\cdot 7=6,999,993$

Comment: I figured it out by doing $\dfrac{1}{7} = 0.142857...$ then $1/7(10^6-\dfrac{1}{7})$ to get the $999,999$. Is that what you did?

Comment: Because when you start the repeat of the decimal again, you have just $1$ left, so the product of any number (not having a factor $2$ or $5$) and the repeat of the decimal is a string of $9$'s of the length of the repeat.  Similarly for $1/13=0.\overline {076923}$ and $13 \cdot 76923=999,999$

Comment: I usually explain it in the following way to my students: Letting $a = 1/7$. Then according to the repeating decimals, we have $10^6 a - a = 142857$ and therefore $10^6 - 1 = 142857 \cdot 7$.

Comment: @RossMillikan Can you elaborate? What do you mean by just 1 left?

Comment: If you think about doing long division of $7$ into $1$ to find the decimal, the first division goes $1$ time with remainder $3$.  The second division goes  $4$ times with remainder $2$.  The remainders will all be distinct.  When you finish the repeat, the remainder is $1$.  That is what "causes" the repeat-you are back where you started doing the division.

Comment: This is how I did it as well

Answer (score 5):

Multipling by $7^2=49$ is the same as multiplying by $50$ then subtracting one copy.

So $$142,857*7^2=142,857*50-142857$$. 
Now,  multipling by 50 is the same as multiplying by 100 then dividing by 2.
so we have $$(142,857*100)/2-142857$$.
Multiplying by 100 is just adding 2 0s:
$$14285700/2-142857$$
Dividing by 2 is easy to do by hand: $$7142850-142857$$
And finally, subtracting two numbers is easy to do by hand: $$6999993$$
Hopefully that's actually right, because I'm not checking :)

Answer (score 3):

If you recognize that those are the decimal digits of $1/7 = .142857142857142857...$, then you realize that $1000000/7$ must be 142857+0.142857, so 142857 must be (100,000 - 1)/7, and you're on your way.